# Error while trying to write a csv file

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write a csv file in RStudio on a MacOS, but I'm getting this error:

> Error: Failed to open '/Users/some.one/Documents/data'

and this is my code:

```
write_csv(dat, path_dat, na = "NA", append = FALSE, col_names = TRUE)
```

can someone maybe tell me what might cause such an error?

Edit:

dat ........... is a data frame

path_dat ...... is the path in the error : /Users/some.one/Documents/data

Comment: What's `path_dat`? Where did `write_csv` come from, its not part of base R? What sort of thing is `dat`?

Comment: That means your directory specification is pointing to a directory that doesn't exist or that doesn't have write permission for the user. Keep in mind that you have to specify the file extension in R, so it should be `/Users/some.one/Documents/data.csv`. Unless data is the folder, then you need to use `/Users/some.one/Documents/data/thefile.csv` See also `?write_csv` for examples.

Comment: @JorisMeys thanks, you just gave me the answer, data is indeed a folder, I did not add the name of my new file

Comment: @Spacedman I apologize for the lack of details, I added some to the question

Answer (score 1):

I would check that you have access to this directory. You can do via `getwd()`

If you don't, you can change the directory you're writing to via `setwd(path_to_directory)` and then run your `write.csv` function.

Comment: I already checked that I can access the directory.

I even tried with setwd more than one path just to be sure, but I always get the same error

Comment: can we see what you're setting ```path_dat``` to and what class type is ```dat```

Comment: I added some details to the question

Comment: thanks for your help,  apparently I forgot to add the name of the new file at the end of the directory, @JorisMeys just gave me the answer